# Problem with integrand in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a function of two variables `f[x, y]` and want to calculate

```
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, -x0, x0}, {y, -y0, y0}]
```

However, the function `f[x, y]` has a complicated structure and contains the following thing,

```
NIntegrate[g[x, y, z], {z, 0, z0}]
```

Therefore, Mathematica says that integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values. How can I fix this?

As minimal working example, one can consider:

```
f[x_, y_] := 
  Module[{g, h}, g = NIntegrate[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2) - z], {z, 0, 10}]; 
   h = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]; g/h];
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

Comment: `NIntegrate` needs to know all the parameters numerically (except x,y)! Your  chance to get help increases if you provide a minimal workingexample!

Comment: `g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := ... ;
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[x, y, z], {z, 0, z0}]; 
NIntegrate[f[x, y] {x, -x0, x0}, {y, -y0, y0}]`

Comment: Artem, did you enter numerical values for x0, y0 and z0?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch yes, of course. I'll update the question in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := 
  Module[{g, h}, g = Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)] NIntegrate[Exp[-z], {z, 0, 10}];
   h = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]; g/h];
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

---

```
5.56808
```

Enjoy the choice.

The reason is the NIntegrate requires the function of integration to be either constant or a function of the integration variable solely.

I think that is not the question but that is the way it is.

The factor Exp[-(x^2+y^2)] is constant the integral exists, the integrant is steady. For the integration NIntegrate is not necesssary.

```
f[x_, y_] := 
  Module[{g, h}, 
   g = Integrate[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)] Exp[-z], {z, 0, 10}];
   h = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]; g/h];
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

---

```
5.56808
```

That is the deepest understanding possible for this question.

Comment: I asked something different but your answer is really helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2) - z]/
 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {z, 0, 10}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

(*  5.56808  *)

Have fun!